# Invalid rangeParameter Tag on ccnet.config cruisecontrol .net version 1.6.7981.1

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I'm trying to configure ccnet.config file with a range of parameters for force build option but the Validator.exe program says:
 "Unable to load array item 'rangeParameter' - Cannot convert from type System.String to ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.Parameters.ParameterBase for object with value:"The type of build to perform.CleanBuildBuild".
I can't find the way and it makes me nervous.....

Thanks a lot and best regards!!!.

this is the project's section:

```
<project name="$(PruebaApplicationProject1)" >
     <workingDirectory>$(DriveCheckOut)$(WorkingMainDir)</workingDirectory>
<artifactDirectory>$(DriveCheckOut)$(WorkingMainDir)$(PruebaApplicationProject1)  $(ArtifactDirectory)</artifactDirectory>
<category>Categoria 1</category>
<webURL>$(ServerName1)$(WorkingMainDir)$(PruebaApplicationProject1)$(ArtifactDirectory)$(ReportName)</webURL>
<labeller type="defaultlabeller">
      <initialBuildLabel>1</initialBuildLabel>
      <prefix>Project1-1-</prefix>
      <incrementOnFailure>true</incrementOnFailure>
      <labelFormat>00000</labelFormat>          
</labeller>
<modificationDelaySeconds>1800</modificationDelaySeconds>
<maxSourceControlRetries>5</maxSourceControlRetries>
<initialState>Stopped</initialState>
<startupMode>UseLastState</startupMode>
<triggers>
     <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="600" buildCondition="ForceBuild"  initialSeconds="600" />
<parameterTrigger>
    <parameters>
        <namedValue name="Type" value="Build"/>
    </parameters >
</parameterTrigger>
</triggers>
     <tasks>
    <nant>
                   <executable>$(NAntDirectory)nant.exe</executable>
         <baseDirectory>$(WorkingMainDir)$(PruebaApplicationProject1)\</baseDirectory>             
         <buildFile>$(PruebaApplicationProject1)$(ExtentionBuildFile)</buildFile>
          <buildArgs>-listener:CCNetListener,CCNetListener</buildArgs>

          <buildTimeoutSeconds>1200</buildTimeoutSeconds>
          <dynamicValues>
            <directValue parameter="Type" property="targetList.target[0]" >
                    <default>Build</default>
            </directValue>
          </dynamicValues>
    </nant>
    </tasks>
    <publishers>
    <statistics />
    <xmllogger logDir="$(DriveCheckOut)$(WorkingMainDir)$(PruebaApplicationProject1)$(ArtifactDirectory)" />
         </publishers>
    <parameters>
    <rangeParameter name="Type">
        <description>The type of build to perform.</description>
            <allowedValues>
                <value>Clean</value>
                <value>Build</value>            
            </allowedValues>
            <default>Build</default>                
        </rangeParameter>
    </parameters>
 </project>
```

Comment: This example was based on wiki section from [link](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parameters)

Answer (score 1):

The `rangeParameter` was renamed to `selectParameter`.

You also need to define the `<trigger />` element within the `<parameterTrigger />` element.

```
<project name="$(PruebaApplicationProject1)" >
     <workingDirectory>$(DriveCheckOut)$(WorkingMainDir)</workingDirectory>
<artifactDirectory>$(DriveCheckOut)$(WorkingMainDir)$(PruebaApplicationProject1)  $(ArtifactDirectory)</artifactDirectory>
<category>Categoria 1</category>
<webURL>$(ServerName1)$(WorkingMainDir)$(PruebaApplicationProject1)$(ArtifactDirectory)$(ReportName)</webURL>
<labeller type="defaultlabeller">
      <initialBuildLabel>1</initialBuildLabel>
      <prefix>Project1-1-</prefix>
      <incrementOnFailure>true</incrementOnFailure>
      <labelFormat>00000</labelFormat>          
</labeller>
<modificationDelaySeconds>1800</modificationDelaySeconds>
<maxSourceControlRetries>5</maxSourceControlRetries>
<initialState>Stopped</initialState>
<startupMode>UseLastState</startupMode>
<triggers>
     <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="600" buildCondition="ForceBuild"  initialSeconds="600" />
<parameterTrigger>
    <parameters>
        <namedValue name="Type" value="Build"/>
    </parameters >
    <trigger type="intervalTrigger" seconds="600" />
</parameterTrigger>
</triggers>
     <tasks>
    <nant>
         <executable>$(NAntDirectory)nant.exe</executable>
         <baseDirectory>$(WorkingMainDir)$(PruebaApplicationProject1)\</baseDirectory>             
         <buildFile>$(PruebaApplicationProject1)$(ExtentionBuildFile)</buildFile>
          <buildArgs>-listener:CCNetListener,CCNetListener</buildArgs>

          <buildTimeoutSeconds>1200</buildTimeoutSeconds>
          <dynamicValues>
            <directValue parameter="Type" property="targetList.target[0]" >
                    <default>Build</default>
            </directValue>
          </dynamicValues>
    </nant>
    </tasks>
    <publishers>
    <statistics />
    <xmllogger logDir="$(DriveCheckOut)$(WorkingMainDir)$(PruebaApplicationProject1)$(ArtifactDirectory)" />
         </publishers>
    <parameters>
    <selectParameter name="Type">
        <description>The type of build to perform.</description>
            <allowedValues>
                <value>Clean</value>
                <value>Build</value>            
            </allowedValues>
            <default>Build</default>                
        </selectParameter>
    </parameters>
 </project>
```